# BLE, Scanning devices with service A or B or C

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I'm executing a scan with `BluetoothLeScanner` to search for devices running one of 3 services.
I've tried adding the services UUIDs to a `ScanFilter` list, but it seems the scan searches for devices running the 3 services.

```
List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
            ScanFilter.Builder sfBuilder = new ScanFilter.Builder();
            sfBuilder.setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(Uuids.A));
            //sfBuilder.setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(Uuids.B));
            //sfBuilder.setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(Uuids.C));
            filters.add(sfBuilder.build());

            ScanSettings.Builder scanSettingsBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();

        mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters,scanSettingsBuilder.build(),mLeScanCallback);
```

Is there a way to pass the 3 UUIDs and the scan returns the devices running 1 or more of those services? (i know i can search for all devices without filters, and after that filter them myself, i was trying to avoid that)

Comment: If the three services have a common part in their UUIDs you can use a mask to exclude the uncommon bits from the search. Post the searched uuids strings please :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can start three scans with a filter, for each service?